# div centering colliding problems

Tags: html, css

my divs won't center no matter what because they  are colliding with eachother, I know its possible to make them  centered with `top`,  `transform: translate()` but then when I resize it looks  terrible, here is the code:

```css
.question-text {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 57vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.question-text2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 0vh;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
  left: calc(50vw + 1rem); 
  top: 26%; 
}
#valueIndex2{
  position: relative;
  color: salmon;
  z-index: 104;
  font-size: 3rem; /* Adjust the value as needed */
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}



#valueIndex{ 
   color: salmon; 
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 3rem;
   width: 49vw;
   height: 0vh;
   display: flex;
   text-align: center;
   justify-content: center;
   padding: 0;
   left: calc(50vw + 1rem); /* Adjust the value as needed */
     top: 35%; /* Adjust the value as needed */
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="pack-term">
        <h2 class="question-text"> 
            <span>${item2.name}</span>
          </h2> 
              <h3 id="valueIndex2"> 
                <span>${item2.value}</span>  
            </h3> 
        </div>

        <div class="pack-term">
            <h3 id="valueIndex"> 
                <span>${item1.value}</span>  
            </h3> 
          <h2 class= "question-text2"> 
        <span>${item1.name}</span> 
     </h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code a little bit:

CSS: I deleted the `text-align` and `justify-content` and edited the `left`

```
.question-text2 {
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 3rem;
 width: 50vw;
 height: 0vh;
 display: flex;

 padding: 0;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
 left: calc(13vw + 6rem); 
 top: 9%; 
 }
```

CSS: If you want to move the `question-text` up or down you just can do that using  top. You can use this code top to move everything down or up.

```
.question-text{
  top: -13px;
}
```

HTML: You have to add `<center>` to your code

```
<center>
 <div class="pack-term">
    <h2 class="question-text"> 
        <span>${item2.name}</span>
      </h2> 
          <h3 id="valueIndex2"> 
            <span>${item2.value}</span>  
        </h3> 
    </div>
  
    <div class="pack-term">
        <h3 id="valueIndex"> 
            <span>${item1.value}</span>  
        </h3> 
      <h2 class= "question-text2"> 
    <span>${item1.name}</span> 
 </h2>
 </div>
 </center>
```

Comment: that kind of works, is there any way i can move the `valueIndex`s up?

Comment: Yes I edited the CSS a little bit

Comment: i mean that works but i still have to bring `questiontext`1 and `questiontext2` to bring up the` valueindexes` is there any way i can just move up the value indexes

Comment: I edited the CSS second time you can try now